# Downloading in real-time 1000s of Telegram chats with Python Telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I have set up a script to download messages from thousands of Telegram supergroups (named `chatlist`). This works fine when I use a few groups, however, allowing 1000< groups seems to break it and no messages are collected at all. Is this the correct way to approach it, or is there a more efficient way? I don't think it's a network issue my end as I have GB internet

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

client = TelegramClient('test', api_id, api_hash)


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chatlist))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    
    message = event.message.to_dict()
    print(message['message'])
    
await client.start()
await client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: What does "seems to break it" mean?

Comment: @AKX, good point - I have updated it, sorry for being vague!

Comment: You would probably need to debug the library a bit to see why nothing happens. I'd bet on there being a limit for `chats=`'s size somewhere.

Comment: as a general rule, when you have code which works for n instances, you can't just increase n by 20000% or the like and expect it to work.  And when you design code to handle n interactions, you set limits to prevent people doing that (good code), or your physical resources set limits when they do (bad code).  Thus likely you need to this in chunks (perhaps parallelised).

Answer (score 1):

A simple workaround is to remove the `NewMessage` event filter i.e.:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage())
```

and filter messages inside the method yourself:

```
async def my_event_handler(event):
    message = event.message.to_dict()
    input_chat = await event.get_input_chat()
    if input_chat in chatlist:
        print(message['message'])
```

You didn't mention what's inside `chatlist`, so I assumed it's a list of `InputChat` objects.

Note that if your chat list is a list of `@username` strings, you'll soon reach Telegram username resolve limits. Always have `InputChat` or long ids in the chatlist.